# VBA WEB CLICKING

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I need a help, i'm trying to "select" the second checkbox (radio) in the website bellow with VBA but I cannot do this, can you help me?

1 - URL = [https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id](https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/historicocotacoes) |||
2 - Button is: Cotações de fechamento de todas as moedas em uma data.
 |||
3 - Click on button "Pesquisar" |||
4 - Download CSV (image bellow) to open those links bellow. |||
4.1 If we can automate this "click" we dont need to look about the date, the web site already do this |||
5 - Also if we can create a loop in the VBA to always change the last number of this URL we can also download the workbook I need to download? |||
6 - Need to save this document in this path: C:\Temp\BASES\TBEX-OB08\todasasmoedas.csv

> LINKS WE CAN AUTOMATE THE LAS NUMBER: Because this link changes all
> day to a +1 number check bellow: 11/08/2021
> https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=61795
> 10/08/2021
> https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=gerarCSVTodasAsMoedas&id=61794

```
    Sub Web_Taxes()

Dim IE As Object
Dim URL As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
URL = "https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/historicocotacoes"

IE.Navigate URL

'Do While IE.busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
'Loop

'Need to select the button bellow in the website, it is the second "radio" button in the website.
'<input name="RadOpcao" id="RadOpcao" onclick="Opcao2()" type="radio" value="2">

IE.document.All.Item("RadOpcao").Item(2).Checked = True

End Sub
```

[This the way I need to search (second button selected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJxVR.png)

Also if you know other method to web **scrape** all the currencies information's by this website please let me know,

Thanks""

Answer (score 0):

After some simple test, I found that the radio button is located in the `iframe` element, and the content of the `iframe` element (ptax.bcb.gov.br) does not belong to the same domain as the parent page ([www.bcb.gov.br](http://www.bcb.gov.br)), so I think it is impossible to get the radio element correctly to achieve automation.

If you need to specify the download file to a specific path, you can also try to use VBA to modify the data in the relevant registry path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`,find Change the value of the string `Download Directory` to the new path you want to assign as IE's Default Download directory.

Or you could change it manually, like this: open IE browser -> setting -> view downloads -> click options in popup -> Browser -> Select specific file path you need.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'as HTML Document Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True ' Set to true to watch what's happening
IE.navigate "https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/historicocotacoes"

Set doc = IE.document
doc.getElementsByName("RadOpcao")(2).checked = True
```

(2) is for the third item (staring with 0) unter the Name"Rad0pcao"

---- maybe it works... for you

If you want to click a button do this:

```
doc.getElementById("ID").Click
```

or this

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAME")(0).Click
```

If you want to select something try

```
doc.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAME")(0).Value = "Value-Name"
```

When you use `getElementsByClassName`, note that this is always an Array, so you have this `(0)` after it, for the first Item in this Array, or you use `(1)` for the second item... and so on.

Maybe it helps you, have fun :D